# sendto() - UDP unicast in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, sendto

I have the function below that sends the `message` to the `next_hop` (e.g. 192.168.0.10) as UDP unicast. When I compile the code I get the following warning `passing argument 2 of 'sendto' makes pointer from integer without a cast` for the line `if(sendto(s, *message, BUFSIZE, 0, &si_other, slen) == -1)`. How can I fix the code? Thank you for the answers.

```
void log_msg_send(char *message, char *next_hop){

struct sockaddr_in si_other;
int s, slen = sizeof(si_other);
int port_no = 3333;
char *nexthop;
unsigned short Server_port;
nexthop = next_hop;
Server_port = port_no;

if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr,"socket error");
    exit(1);
}

memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_other.sin_port = htons(Server_port);

if(inet_aton(nexthop, &si_other.sin_addr) == 0){
    fprintf(stderr,"socket error");
    exit(1);
}

if(sendto(s, *message, BUFSIZE, 0, &si_other, slen) == -1){
    fprintf(stderr,"socket error");
    exit(1);
}

close(s);
```

}

Comment: Why are you dereferencing `message` anyways?

Comment: I removed *, now I get the following warning "passing argument 5 of 'sendto' from incompatible pointer type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char * message
```

Means:

```
(char *) message // message is a pointer-to-char
```

And:

```
char (*message) // *message is a char
```

So when you need to pass a `char*`, use `message`. If you need the first char in that buffer, use `*message`.

---

Warning:

```
char * a, b;
```

Makes `a` a `char*`, but `b` a plain `char`, wherever you put spaces.

---

The fifth argument might need to be cast to a `struct sockaddr*` manually, depending on how it is prototyped on your system.